# Getting date as string - need to convert

Tags: apache-flex, date

Programming in Flex 4.5

I'm getting a date as a String.

I don't know what date or hour I'm getting.

I want to convert the string to date and take only the hours & minutes.

For example:

Getting - "2012-02-07T13:35:46+02:00"

I want to see: 13:35.

Suggestions or any other solutions?

**After some digging, Solution:**

```
var myDate:Date;

myDate = DateFormmater.parseDateString(myDateString);

var dateResult:String = myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes();
```

Thanks anyway! :-)!

Comment: [Check The Link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=08_Dates_and_times_3.html)

Comment: Been there, it doesnt help because im getting a string and i have no idea whats in it or how it is presented.. i just know that i need to get the hours & minutes from there.

Comment: Then use the .substr(12,16),Cause it had a Standard format.so That method only give you Time

Comment: Isn't your string is already formatted? For example like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Comment: Ok, after some digging i found the answer:

var myDate:String;

myDate = DateFormmater.parseDateString(myDateString);

var dateResult:String = myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes();

Thanks anyway! :-)!

Comment: I've just posted a similar answer. Once your date format is certain you can cast your string to date and retrieve hours and minutes with 'get' methods.

Comment: If you feel your own answer is better than the others, you should add it as an answer (not as an edit to your question) and accept it. This is clearer for other users who visit this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use date.getHours() and date.getMinutes(). Try the following:

```
var d:Date = DateField.stringToDate("your_date_string","YYYY-MM-DD");
trace("hours: ", date.getHours()); // returns 13
trace("minutes: ", date.getMinutes()); // returns 35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function init():void  
{           
    var isoStr:String = "2012-02-07T13:35:46+02:00";         
    var d:Date = new Date;       
    d = isoToDate(isoStr)    
    trace(d.hours);  
}

private function isoToDate(value:String):Date  
{   
    var dateStr:String = value;   
    dateStr = dateStr.replace(/\-/g, "/");    
    dateStr = dateStr.replace("T", " ");     
    dateStr = dateStr.replace("+02:00", " GMT-0000");   
    return new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already got the answer, but for future users, here it is.

```
var myDateString:String="2012-02-07T13:35:46+02:00"

//This is of the format <yyyy-mm-dd>T<hh:mm:ss><UTC-OFFSET AS hh:mm>
//You could write your own function to parse it, or use Flex's DateFormatter class

var myDate:Date=DateFormatter.parseDateString(myDateString);

//Now, myDate has the date as a Flex Date type.
//You can use the various date functions. In this case,

trace(myDate.getHours()); //Traces the hh value
trace(myDate.getMinutes()); //Traces the mm value
```